# XAML Hot reload not working with custom build configurations

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, msbuild, uwp-xaml

I'm working on a UWP project currently which is very XAML oriented. So far we've used the default `Debug` configuration to test and develop the application.

Things have changed and now we have different switches that are toggled via the Configuration Manager (e.g. build versions for a testing environment).

Unfortunately, I'm now unable to use XAML Hot Reload, even though I've followed the MSDN guidelines [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019) as well as adding `<DisableXbfLineInfo>False</DisableXbfLineInfo>` to the configuration.

Has anyone ever encountered this similar issue and can provide some additional insight?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69064159/4342563