# How do I add XamlDebuggingInformation MSBuild property to CsProj?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, msbuild, csproj

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019) from Microsoft about trubleshooting XAML Hot reload says this:

> By default, source info is included in a Debug configuration. It is controlled by MSBuild properties in your project files (such as *.csproj). For WPF, the property is XamlDebuggingInformation, which must be set to True. For UWP, the property is DisableXbfLineInfo, which must be set to False. For example:
>
> WPF: `<XamlDebuggingInformation>True</XamlDebuggingInformation>`
>
> UWP: `<DisableXbfLineInfo>False</DisableXbfLineInfo>`

Since my project configuration name isn't "Debug" the hot reload property is not automatically in my MSBuild configuration and as you can see Microsoft recommend that I add `XamlDebuggingInformation` to my .csProj in order to get XAML hotreloading to work but I have no idea how todo that.

I tried just adding a new line into the `<PropertyGroup>` tag that had the configuration I wanted to apply but then Visual Studio had a very hard time loading after that. How do I add this MSBuild property?

Example of csproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="16.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{1EA7A7EC-D092-4DE3-B8DD-49F74B71ACF2}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>PatchDeDup</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>PatchDeDup</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'OtherDebug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\OtherDebug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ... file includes, dependency references, etc. (pretty generic wpf project stuff)
```

I assumed that I'd have to add `<XamlDebuggingInformation>True</XamlDebuggingInformation>` inside the `PropertyGroup` for the `OtherDebug|AnyCPU` but VS 2019 doesn't expect that apparently...

Comment: Hard time loading? What version of VS are you using and how does your project file look like?

Comment: It was vs 2019 and it pretty much got stuck in an infinite loop after telling me the project was not valid. I've updated the question with an example of what I'm working with

Comment: Did you insert like this
`<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'OtherDebug|AnyCPU'">
 <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
...
 <XamlDebuggingInformation>True</XamlDebuggingInformation>
</PropertyGroup>`

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it. The actual position inside the PropertyGroup might have been different (I wouldn't think that matters)

Comment: Tested on my side and the project loaded well, the <XamlDebuggingInformation> property should insert like this and it will not affect the project loading. Have you tried on a simple WPF project? Whether once you remove this property code line and everything works as usual?

Comment: Hmm, I went and did the same changes I did the first time while VS was closed (So I didn't have to reload while it was open) and everything seems to work fine now... Strange :)

Comment: Great, indeed, it is strange, I suppose sometimes, cache or other things may affect VS, but not sure. Since your issue has been solved, you can summarize and post an answer then accept it, this will still benefit other forum members who meet the similar issues. Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution ended up being really simple. Open the `.csProj` file find the `PropertyGroup` which has the configuration name you expect and add `<XamlDebuggingInformation>True</XamlDebuggingInformation>` into the body of the XML tag.

For me I had todo this while Visual Studio was closed cause the Solution Reload failed and  Visual Studio got stuck in an infinite loop. But adding it before opening was fine :)